# how to fix VBA Code that is sending duplicate emails instead of attaching the whole excel file

Tags: excel, vba, sendmail

I added a code to filter cells that contains "AD" before sending the mail to a specific recipient. but instead just sending one email, it is sending multiple mails depending on how many lines is the AD

```
Sub Rectangle7_Click()

Const cFirst As Integer = 20
Const cLast As Integer = 65
Const cRequest As String = "New Request"

Dim i As Integer
For i = cFirst To cLast


If Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Provide the PC name from KE53"
Exit Sub


ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please provide the user responsible (Sector) maintained in KE53 
for this PC"
Exit Sub

ElseIf Range("K" & i).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Provide the company code where the PC needs to be extended"

Exit Sub
End If

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="PROFITCENTER"
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$19:$L$65").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=AD*", 
_
Operator:=xlAnd


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Apps\" & "Request" & Format(Now(), 
"DD-MM-YYYY"), _


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
    .To = 
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = " Request_" & "" & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")
    .HTMLBODY = "Thank You"
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Display

End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Next
End Sub
```

kindly help me what gone wrong why it is sending multiple email instead of just attaching the whole sheet?

Comment: you have a loop inside. exit the loop before the Outlook function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Sub Rectangle7_Click()

    Const cFirst As Integer = 20
    Const cLast As Integer = 65
    Const cRequest As String = "New Request"

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = cFirst To cLast
        If Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Provide the PC name from KE53"
            Exit Sub

        ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please provide the user responsible (Sector) maintained in KE53 for this PC"
            Exit Sub

        ElseIf Range("K" & i).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Provide the company code where the PC needs to be extended"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="PROFITCENTER"
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$19:$L$65").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=AD*", Operator:=xlAnd

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Apps\" & "Request" & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = " Request_" & "" & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")
        .HTMLBODY = "Thank You"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Display

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```